# Trying to access a variable inside a block

Tags: ruby, rss

I'm trying to make a simple rss generator. My initialize method works fine and the update method runs without an error too but the new item in the update method never get added to the rss feed. I think it has something to do with how i'm accessing the variable 'maker' but i'm not sure.

```
require "rss"

class RSS_Engine
  def initialize
    @rss = RSS::Maker.make("atom") do |maker|
      maker.channel.author = "Jamie"
      maker.channel.updated = Time.now.to_s
      maker.channel.about = "http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/feeds/news.rss"
      maker.channel.title = "Example Feed"
      @maker = maker
    end
  end

  def update
    @maker.items.new_item do |item|
      item.title = "Test"
      item.updated = Time.now.to_s
    end
  end

  def print_rss
    puts @rss
  end
end

rss = RSS_Engine.new
rss.update
rss.print_rss
```

I got the original code from this example:

```
rss = RSS::Maker.make("atom") do |maker|
  maker.channel.author = "matz"
  maker.channel.updated = Time.now.to_s
  maker.channel.about = "http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/feeds/news.rss"
  maker.channel.title = "Example Feed"

  maker.items.new_item do |item|
  item.link = "http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2010/12/25/ruby-1-9-2-p136-is-released/"
  item.title = "Ruby 1.9.2-p136 is released"
  item.updated = Time.now.to_s
end
```

This code works fine but i want to be able to add new posts to the rss feed over time so i'm trying to put the 'new.item' bit into it's own method.

Comment: Do not use tabulators in Ruby code.

Comment: If you add a `p @maker` as the first line of your update method, what is printed?

Comment: I get about 100 lines of code. It starts with #<RSS::Maker::Atom::Feed:0x007ff0b3c835b0 @maker=#<RSS::Maker::Atom::Feed:0x007ff0b3c835b0 ...>,
Would you like me to post the whole thing? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not `@maker` variable, you have to invoke `to_feed` method to regenerate the feed after you modify it out of the code block.

So you need to add `@rss = @maker.to_feed` at the end of your `update` method.

One more thing about creating a new feed entry, *link* or *id* attribute need to be set.

Below code will work for you:

```
 def update
    @maker.items.new_item do |item|
      item.link = "http://test.com"
      item.title = "Test"
      item.updated = Time.now.to_s
    end
    @rss = @maker.to_feed
  end
```

If you are interested about why, you can take a look ruby rss source code. And below code(under *rss/maker/base.rb*) is the root cause why you need to invoke `to_feed` method if you modify feed out of the block:

```
  def make(*args, &block)
      new(*args).make(&block)
  end

  def make
    yield(self)
    to_feed
  end
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple. Thank you.